# How do you get the address of the last non-blank cell in a column?

Tags: google-sheets

I use this to get the contents of the last cell in a column: `=INDEX(FILTER(C:C,NOT(ISBLANK(C:C))),ROWS(FILTER(C:C,NOT(ISBLANK(C:C)))))`
But I want the ***address*** of that last cell. Does anyone know what I can use? Thanks.

Comment: you can try the function `=ADDRESS(row,column,1)`

Answer (score 1):

Formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA("C"&MAX(IF(ISBLANK(C:C),,ROW(C:C)))
```

Explanation

We know that the column is C, so the above formula concatenates C to the the row number of the last non-blank (non-empty) cell which is returned by `MAX(IF(ISBLANK(C:C),,ROW(C:C))`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the shortest way to accomplish it:

```
="C"&max(filter(row(C:C),search(,C:C)))
```

The irony of this solution is `search` returns everything but a blank when you ask it to find blank.

Answer (score 0):

="C"&counta(C:C)+1 maybe? need to add more characters to be able so save the answer